# How can a modal fetch data from an image?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am developing a hostel admin page. I am now constructing codes for checkout. I have here an image and it triggers a modal. The image fetch the value of "room_id" from sql. here is how I get the rooms with its image:

```
<?php
     include('db.php');
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms order by room_name asc";
      {
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            if ($row["room_type"]=="DELUXE")
            {
                if ($row["room_status"]=='AVAILABLE')
                { 
?>
```

Then I display it like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <td><a href="../admin pages/rooms/CheckIn.php?room_id=<?php echo $row["room_id"]; ?>" onclick="return confirm('CheckIn?')"><img src='../dist/img/Green bed.PNG'/></a>

    <?php } else if($row["room_status"]=='UNAVAILABLE'){ ?>
    <td><img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-danger" src='../dist/img/Red bed.PNG'  name="ToOut" value="<?php echo $row["room_id"];?>">
    javascript:document.forms['frmbrand'].hidbrand.value = this.value;
    <?php } ?>
    </form>
    <br><b><?php echo $row["room_type"]; ?></b><small><?php echo $row["room_name"]; echo $row["room_id"]; ?></small><i><span> Php<?php echo $row["room_price"]; ?>.00</span></i></td>
  <?php }}} ?>
```

Then I have a modal for check out which is triggered as the image is clicked:

```
<div class="modal modal-danger fade" id="modal-danger">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Billing</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <?php ECHO $_POST["ToOut"];?>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#add">Extra Room Service</a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" href="rooms/CheckOut.php?room_id=<?php echo $row["room_id"]; ?>">Check Out</a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add">Extra Room Service</a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add">Add Orders</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The checkout page is working.  I discovered that the modal doesn't
fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

The value field is used for input tags, not img tags. Instead of storing the value on an img tag, you can use a hidden input type. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ToOut" value="<?php echo $row["room_id"];?>" />.
```

Place this somewhere in your form. Using hidden input, the element will not be display anywhere in your form, but the information is passed when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Isaiah then there is something else wrong. If you placed this code inside your form it is guaranteed to work.